# Docker container error cannot find module '/app/npm'

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, dockerfile

I'm new to Docker and when I build my image everything is successful, but when I run it I get this error.

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/app/npm '
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:lts-alpine@sha256:72a490e7ed8aed68e16b8dc8f37b5bcc35c5b5c56ee3256effcdee63e2546f93

WORKDIR /app
COPY --chown=node:node package*.json .

RUN npm ci --only=production
COPY --chown=node:node . .

EXPOSE 3000

USER node
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

The command I run

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 -rm <image name>
```

Comment: May I know what is that image you are trying to pull?

Comment: Working here... What is the "dev", script?

Comment: @HosseinHeydari I'm just pulling the latest stable version of Node from alpine

Comment: @madflow I assumed it should be working... Could it be a caching issue on my end maybe if I rebuild the image a couple of times? The dev script is "nuxi dev" for nuxt 3

Comment: Some some random ideas: use node image `FROM node:version`, do not run development mode in container and try to get a shell from the container using `docker exec -it container_id sh` and try to run your app from there, also you should know about the container entrypoint, cmd will be executed after entrypoint, what is the entrypoint in your case?